# Mongoose not accept number begin with 0

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I try to save a french number phone, ex : 060908...

This is my body request :

```
newAppointment.phone = req.body.phone;
```

My schema :

```
phone: {
            type:Number,
            required: true
        }
```

and my data : 06

This return me an error : **SyntaxError: Unexpected number**. When i convert it to string it's **remove** the 0.

Answer : Use **STRING**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a phone like **0609084542** you cannot use a `Number` field. Use a `String` field instead.

```
phone: {
      type: String,
      required: true
}
```

---

I think you need some help about types (*String, Number aka Int/Char/Long/Float/Double*).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047982/javascript-0-in-beginning-of-number) you have a stack overflow post speaking about the leading **0** in numbers. Like:

```
const toto = 0652;
```

---

**To be known**:

```
const toto = 0652;
```

is different than

```
const toto = 652;
```

is different than

```
const toto = '0652';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want 0 at first place. You have to take phone type as string in your schema because we know placing 0 at first place will not change the number's value

so, your schema is like:

```
phone: {
      type: String,
      required: true
}
```

and then sends your data as " 0609084542"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a get / set mechanism if you really wish to store a phone number as a number. So, your schema could definitely insert a phone number into a number, however, the set would convert the string into a number, by simply removing the leading 0, and then the get, could convert the number into a string, placing the leading 0 back in front.

```
phone: { type: Number, get: v => v.slice(1)*1, set: v => '0'+v.toString() }

toJSON: { getters: true };
```