# Number begins with 0 gives a awkward value

Tags: javascript, numbers

In javascript every variable we declare as var `var` irrespective of data type(int,String etc).

I got shocked when I faced something in javascript when trying to print a number begins with 0, it prints a awkward number.

E.G.

```
 var x=0622211646;

console.log(x); it prints this number :105452454
```

Why such awkward happens in javascript?

Comment: It's [Octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) notation

Comment: Here is a good explanaition about leading 0 [Leading 0 in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047982/javascript-0-in-beginning-of-number)