# Numbers are not displayed properly in console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, console.log

I recently encountered a weird behavior while using Javascript in NodeJS and chrome. It looks like it doesn't support some numbers.
When I do `console.log(05042020)` it displays 13128144. It happens in NodeJS and Chrome but when I do console.log(1000000000) it prints fine.

Please see the screenshot attached as a proof.enter image description here:

[image]

Comment: Because. it is octal

Comment: Without strict mode, a zero-prefix marks an octal number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047982/javascript-0-in-beginning-of-number

Comment: Thank You. I was trying to store dates. I guess I would use strings to store them.