# arguments starting with 0 giving different numbers than intended in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arguments, zero

when I try to get arguments starting with 0, like this case here 012 it is transferring it to 010 why is that can someone explain?

```js
function func1(a, b, c) {
  console.log(arguments[0]);

  console.log(arguments[1]);
  
  console.log(arguments[2]);
}

func1(1, 012, 3);
```

[MDN screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Ezj.png)

Comment: How is your expected output "2" on second index, when you pass "012"?

Comment: Images are not code. Show code. You can even write it so it runs here. Use the tools provided please.

Comment: There is a good amount of information around this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047982/javascript-0-in-beginning-of-number).

Comment: In Javascript a number starting with 0 is interpreted as octal.

Answer (score 0):

In JS the leading `0` converts the given number in octal base so `012 = (12)8 = (10)10`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript a number starting with 0 is interpreted as octal.

**BUT** the console log is showing it to you in decimal.

012 = 1*8 + 2 in decimal which is 10.